# Spring AMQP: How to dynamically adjust the concurrentConsumers?

Tags: spring-amqp

The Spring AMQP doc says

> "Since version 1.3.0, you can now dynamically adjust the
>   concurrentConsumers property."

How do you do that? Thru environment variable or what? Elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setConcurrentConsumers()` on the listener container...

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Changing consumers from " + this.concurrentConsumers + " to " + concurrentConsumers);
}
```

The number of consumers will be increased or decreased as needed.

Comment: Ah I thought it meant something like Spring Cloud Config